# Can Delphi XE5 produce apps for Windows 8 RT and Windows Phone 8?

Tags: delphi, windows-phone-8, windows-8, delphi-xe5

Is it possible to use Delphi XE5 or RAD Studio XE5 to create apps for Windows 8 RT (ARM based tablets) and Windows Phone 8, using the same code (Firemonkey) as for Android and iOS?

I searched Embarcadero's website on [windows development](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/windows-development) but it goes a long way to avoid mentioning Windows 8 RT and Windows Phone 8. It states that

> Your apps will run on Windows desktops and x86 based tablets with Intel and Intel Atom hardware such as Microsoft Surface Professional, Slate tablets from HP, Asus and others, as well as AMD processor based tablets from Acer, Samsung and more.

Does this mean that Windows 8 RT and Windows Phone 8 are not supported by Delphi/RAD Studio XE5?

Comment: There were unofficial hackerish efforts to make hello-world grade app for winRT x86. This was just prove of concept and never ready for production. Embarcadero probably even did not accomplished that

Comment: @Arioch'The That was all before the WinRT lock down was introduced. It cannot be done now.

Comment: "Your apps will run on Windows desktops and x86 based tablets " - it should be noted that as of now they will NOT run on x86-based tablets that run Android for x86; currently Android support is limited to ARM.

Comment: Any news about Windows (Mobile = Windows 10 on phones) platform? Maybe newest release of RAD Studio (10 Seattle) added some new features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi XE5 cannot produce apps that run on WinRT or Win Phone 8.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Do you know if this is something that will be supported in the near future?

Comment: Well, only Emba know that, but I personally very much doubt it. There are technical reasons why WinRT cannot be supported at the moment. And there is a lot of doubt over the future of WinRT. It has been a total disaster in terms of volume of shipped units. Julia Larson-Green recently said *We aren't going to have three different versions of Windows*. Not clear what that means but expect WinRT either to die, or merge with WinPhone. I doubt Emba will commit resources to these platforms until their futures are more stable. I know I would treat that as being toxic.

Comment: If I were to start developing for either of those platforms, I'd look to use the native tools. Visual Studio with C# would be my choice.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking of. I just wanted to make sure that I should not try Delphi. You have saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

Work is being done on Windows ARM/RT, Linux Server, TBD.

Take a look Embarcadero RAD Studio Roadmap

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42544

[image]

Comment: That doesn't mean that work is being done. Remember what the road map looked like back in 2005!!

Comment: @Sayat TBD stands for "To Be Determined". :-) In regard to Linux server, Allen Bauer mentioned on his blog that they were "considering adding it to the roadmap", which I commented was as much a commitment as my considering adding "Climb Mt. Everest" to my to-do list. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To confirm David's accepted answer, I just received a response from Embarcadero support:

> Yes, you are correct we *DO NOT* support Win8 RT or WinPhone8 with Firemonkey. We have not seen a huge demand for these platforms, if there is an increase in demand they might be support, but at the moment we are not supporting them sorry.

So it does not sound like they have any plans to support those platforms in the near future.

Comment: I think that in order to support either platform, Emba would need to dig out their .net compiler and port FMX to that. I cannot see that happening. For native code, as opposed to CLR code, neither platform is open.