# Can Delphi XE5 produce apps for Windows 8?

Tags: delphi, windows-8, delphi-xe5

I'm curious can I build applications for Windows 8 store in Delphi XE5?
*(You know, the ones that look like tiles.)*

I've searched Embarcadero's website. It states that

> Your apps will run on Windows desktops and x86 based tablets with
>   Intel and Intel Atom hardware such as Microsoft Surface Professional,
>   Slate tablets from HP, Asus and others, as well as AMD processor based
>   tablets from Acer, Samsung and more.

From this description, it seems that windows store apps are supported. Am I right?

Comment: No. Delphi cannot produce WinRT applications. Asked e.g. [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20901208/960757), or [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21125783/960757)...

Comment: @TLama, not WinRT, but at least applications for Windows 8 and Windows 8.1? (I've seen question about WinRT and WP8)

Comment: @naXa: Of course you can create native Windows applications. But not the ones that look like tiles.

Comment: Actually, you can create apps that LOOK like tiles, but they are simply native apps emulating the look. They are not WinRT apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delphi XE5 cannot produce Windows Store apps.